# Having to separate Edits for different columns in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am having an issues trying to update different columns in a Gridview separately.

Below is a picture which shows the two columns, after the the edit button has been pressed. Both is editable, and both buttons have turned into the usual Update/Cancel buttons.

[image: Image of the Gridview]

I need to be able to update the specific column based on what update button i press in this code:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
         *some code*
    }
```

I've tried using onclick for one field and the commandArgument for the other, but I am having trouble getting the rowIndex and fieldValue using an onclick.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `RowCommand` event, and use separate `CommandName` values for the two update buttons.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   switch(e.CommandName)
   {
      case "Update1":
         // handle things
         break;
      case "Update2":
        // handle things
         break;
   }
}
```

However, using custom `CommandName` values will probably require you to write your own handler for the `Update` function, the way you would with any other custom `GridView` button.